# Synch 2 audio streams with python

Tags: python, audio, synchronization

Here is my needs: I record two audio streams (raw) using gstreamer and python. There is no drift between the two steams but there is a delta. Pic of the inter-correlation function could give me the delta value.

I have no experience in audio loading/processing with python. Since this procedure is not difficult.. May I ask for advises about libraries to use, and sample code to do so ?

In brief:

```
1) load raw audios files with python
2) compute inter-correlation
3) shift one audio streams by delta to synchronise both stream
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is that your audio is out of synch to begin with? That is an unusual problem. I ask not to be a jerk/PITA, but because I want to make sure I am understanding your problem.

Comment: I am recording from two different usb sources.

Comment: Well, it depends on if they are recordings of the same thing (a miked guitar amp and a "direct" guitar) vs different things (kick and a snar drum). It also depends on your requirements: do you need get the sounds in phase, sample-accurate, or sub-sample accurate, for example? Also, with separate devices, you have two clocks, which means there IS drift. Provided your recordings are short enough, hopefully the drift won't be noticeable.